# Is there a better way to deal with row dependency within a group when performing some calculations on a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe and for some columns the one row is conditional on previous row's value. Also this dependence is only within a group identified by for example, 'gid'.

What I did is basically create another dataframe and then transpose the column(s) used for calculations. The steps I used in the attached code are the following.

1. This is the original dataframe:

```
    gid  id         x         y
0     1   0  1.624345  0.876389
1     1   1 -0.611756  0.894607
2     1   2 -0.528172  0.085044
3     1   3 -1.072969  0.039055
4     1   4  0.865408  0.169830
5     2   0 -2.301539  0.878143
6     2   1  1.744812  0.098347
7     2   2 -0.761207  0.421108
8     2   3  0.319039  0.957890
9     2   4 -0.249370  0.533165
10    3   0  1.462108  0.691877
11    3   1 -2.060141  0.315516
12    3   2 -0.322417  0.686501
13    3   3 -0.384054  0.834626
14    3   4  1.133769  0.018288
```

2. This is the second dataframe I created after transposing:

```
           x0        x1        x2        x3        x4        y0        y1  \
gid                                                                         
1    1.624345 -0.611756 -0.528172 -1.072969  0.865408  0.876389  0.894607   
2   -2.301539  1.744812 -0.761207  0.319039 -0.249370  0.878143  0.098347   
3    1.462108 -2.060141 -0.322417 -0.384054  1.133769  0.691877  0.315516   

           y2        y3        y4  
gid                                
1    0.085044  0.039055  0.169830  
2    0.421108  0.957890  0.533165  
3    0.686501  0.834626  0.018288
```

3. Then I merge two to so I have same number of rows on the second dataframe.

```
    gid        x0        x1        x2        x3        x4        y0        y1  \
0     1  1.624345 -0.611756 -0.528172 -1.072969  0.865408  0.876389  0.894607   
1     1  1.624345 -0.611756 -0.528172 -1.072969  0.865408  0.876389  0.894607   
2     1  1.624345 -0.611756 -0.528172 -1.072969  0.865408  0.876389  0.894607   
3     1  1.624345 -0.611756 -0.528172 -1.072969  0.865408  0.876389  0.894607   
4     1  1.624345 -0.611756 -0.528172 -1.072969  0.865408  0.876389  0.894607   
5     2 -2.301539  1.744812 -0.761207  0.319039 -0.249370  0.878143  0.098347   
6     2 -2.301539  1.744812 -0.761207  0.319039 -0.249370  0.878143  0.098347   
7     2 -2.301539  1.744812 -0.761207  0.319039 -0.249370  0.878143  0.098347   
8     2 -2.301539  1.744812 -0.761207  0.319039 -0.249370  0.878143  0.098347   
9     2 -2.301539  1.744812 -0.761207  0.319039 -0.249370  0.878143  0.098347   
10    3  1.462108 -2.060141 -0.322417 -0.384054  1.133769  0.691877  0.315516   
11    3  1.462108 -2.060141 -0.322417 -0.384054  1.133769  0.691877  0.315516   
12    3  1.462108 -2.060141 -0.322417 -0.384054  1.133769  0.691877  0.315516   
13    3  1.462108 -2.060141 -0.322417 -0.384054  1.133769  0.691877  0.315516   
14    3  1.462108 -2.060141 -0.322417 -0.384054  1.133769  0.691877  0.315516   

          y2        y3        y4  id  
0   0.085044  0.039055  0.169830   0  
1   0.085044  0.039055  0.169830   1  
2   0.085044  0.039055  0.169830   2  
3   0.085044  0.039055  0.169830   3  
4   0.085044  0.039055  0.169830   4  
5   0.421108  0.957890  0.533165   0  
6   0.421108  0.957890  0.533165   1  
7   0.421108  0.957890  0.533165   2  
8   0.421108  0.957890  0.533165   3  
9   0.421108  0.957890  0.533165   4  
10  0.686501  0.834626  0.018288   0  
11  0.686501  0.834626  0.018288   1  
12  0.686501  0.834626  0.018288   2  
13  0.686501  0.834626  0.018288   3  
14  0.686501  0.834626  0.018288   4
```

4. The I use a for loop to calculate columns 'x1 - x4' ('x0' is initial value, so no change is needed), then take the last row for each group and stack it.

```
    gid    output  id
0     1  1.624345   0
1     1  2.518952   1
2     1  2.603996   2
3     1  2.643051   3
4     1  2.812881   4
5     2 -2.301539   0
6     2  1.744812   1
7     2  2.165919   2
8     2  3.123809   3
9     2  3.656974   4
10    3  1.462108   0
11    3  1.777624   1
12    3  2.464124   2
13    3  3.298750   3
14    3  3.317038   4
```

5. Final step is to merge them and get what I want

```
    gid  id         x         y    output
0     1   0  1.624345  0.876389  1.624345
1     1   1 -0.611756  0.894607  2.518952
2     1   2 -0.528172  0.085044  2.603996
3     1   3 -1.072969  0.039055  2.643051
4     1   4  0.865408  0.169830  2.812881
5     2   0 -2.301539  0.878143 -2.301539
6     2   1  1.744812  0.098347  1.744812
7     2   2 -0.761207  0.421108  2.165919
8     2   3  0.319039  0.957890  3.123809
9     2   4 -0.249370  0.533165  3.656974
10    3   0  1.462108  0.691877  1.462108
11    3   1 -2.060141  0.315516  1.777624
12    3   2 -0.322417  0.686501  2.464124
13    3   3 -0.384054  0.834626  3.298750
14    3   4  1.133769  0.018288  3.317038
```

However I think there must be some better ways to achieve the same goal. I am thinking to use groupby and then apply by using the id column, but have not figured out how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

The complete code is attached.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# 1.
df = pd.DataFrame({'gid':np.repeat([1,2,3], 5), 
                   'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] *3, 
                   'x': np.random.randn(15),
                   'y': np.random.random(15)})

# 2.
columns = ['gid', 'id', 'x', 'y']
_df = df[columns].set_index(['gid', 'id']).unstack()
_df.columns = _df.columns.map(lambda x: '{}{}'.format(x[0], x[1]))

# 3.
_df = _df.join(df.set_index('gid')['id'], 
               how='left').reset_index().set_index(df.index)

# 4.
for i in range(1, 5):
    _df['x' + str(i)] = np.fmax(_df['x' + str(i)], _df['x' + str(i - 1)] + _df['y' + str(i)])

columns = pd.Index([column for column in _df.columns
                    if column.find('x') >= 0], name='x')
_df = _df.reindex(columns=columns).groupby(_df['gid']).last()
_df = _df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'output'}).drop('x', axis=1)
_df['id'] = _df.groupby('gid').cumcount()

# 5.
df = df.join(_df[['output']])
```

Comment: I added some comments in the code. Basically you take the last row in each group and stack it.

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html on stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will do the job, much simple.

```
def myfunc(df, id=0, column='x'):
    return np.fmax(df.loc[df['id'] == id, column], 
                   np.add(df.loc[df['id'] == id - 1, column], 
                          df.loc[df['id'] == id, 'y']))

for id in range(1, 5):
    df_1.loc[df_1['id'] == id, 'x'] = \
        df_1.groupby('gid').apply(myfunc, id=id).values
```

Comment: However the first method is much faster than the second method: approximately 50 times faster.